# Tidyquant tq_get and tq_transmute: Warning message "missing values removed from data"

Tags: r, stock, tidyquant

I am getting the following error message from the code below:

```
In to_period(xx, period = on.opts[[period]], ...) :
  missing values removed from data*
```

It works with some stocks, but some get the same error message as this one. Should I just use na.omit(N225) before tq_transmute?

```
N225 <- tq_get("^N225",   
               from = "2016-01-01",
               to = "2020-12-31",
               get = "stock.prices")
    
N225_monthly_returns <- N225 %>%
      tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
                   mutate_fun = periodReturn,
                   period = "monthly",
                   col_rename = "n225_returns")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `na.omit` drops the `NA` rows and doesn't give any warnings. It also gives the same output as the one without using `na.omit` so we don't loose any rows.

```
library(tidyquant)

N225_monthly_returns1 <- N225 %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",
               col_rename = "n225_returns")

N225_monthly_returns2 <- na.omit(N225) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",
               col_rename = "n225_returns")

identical(N225_monthly_returns1, N225_monthly_returns2)
#[1] TRUE
```